# How to return the most right positive nums array cut?

Tags: java, arrays

My task: The input is a one-dimensional array. It is necessary to find the range of maximum width, the elements of which are positive (greater than 0).
As a response, there should be an array of 2 elements, where:
- Element number 0 - the index element of the left border of the segment;
- Element №1 - the index of the element of the right border of the segment.

If there are several such segments, return the RIGHT. If there is no such segment in the array (all numbers are negative), return an empty array.
I don't understand what i do wrong. There's my code:

```
public class ArrayUtils {
public static int[] lookFor(int[] array) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    int firstIndex = 0;
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int sequenceLength = 0;
    int currentSequenceLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            if ( currentSequenceLength == 0 ) {
                firstIndex = i;
            }

            currentSequenceLength += 1;
            lastIndex = i;
        } else {
    if (currentSequenceLength > sequenceLength) {
        sequenceLength = currentSequenceLength;
        result[0] = firstIndex;
        result[1] = lastIndex;
    }
            currentSequenceLength = 0;
        }
    }


    if (sequenceLength == 0) {
        return new int[0];
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: *I don't understand what i do wrong*: how do you know that you're doing something wrong in the first place? What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Knowing what the problem is is the first step in finding a fix. I would start by indenting the code properly to make it readable.

Comment: What do you mean by saying" indenting the code properly"?

Comment: Look at the code in Eran's answer: every time a block is opened with `{`, the body of the block is written 4 spaces to the right. That's called indentation. Not look at your code: the method declaration is at the same level as the class definition, the if block contained inside an else block, which is itself inside a for block, is at the same level as its grandparent for block. That makes your code very hard to read because the structure is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. `if there are several such segments, return the RIGHT` - this means you should replace the previous longest sequence with the current one even if they have the same length. i.e. `if (currentSequenceLength > sequenceLength)` should be `if (currentSequenceLength >= sequenceLength)`.
2. You ignore any sequence that ends at the last index of the array. You should handle it after the loop by adding:

   ```
   if (currentSequenceLength >= sequenceLength) {
       sequenceLength = currentSequenceLength;
       result[0] = firstIndex;
       result[1] = lastIndex;
   }
   ```

To summarize, your method should look like this:

```
public static int[] lookFor(int[] array) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    int firstIndex = 0;
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int sequenceLength = 0;
    int currentSequenceLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            if ( currentSequenceLength == 0 ) {
                firstIndex = i;
            }

            currentSequenceLength += 1;
            lastIndex = i;
        } else {
            if (currentSequenceLength >= sequenceLength) {
                sequenceLength = currentSequenceLength;
                result[0] = firstIndex;
                result[1] = lastIndex;
            }
            currentSequenceLength = 0;
        }
    }
    if (currentSequenceLength >= sequenceLength) {
        sequenceLength = currentSequenceLength;
        result[0] = firstIndex;
        result[1] = lastIndex;
    }


    if (sequenceLength == 0) {
        return new int[0];
    }

    return result;
}
```